# Cast case expression within stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm newbie in Transact-Sql, I created this stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Passed_Time_Day
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @LaDate date ,
    @LeCollaborateur int null,
    @LEquipe int null 
AS
    SELECT
        [dbo].[Pointage].[Id], [dbo].[Pointage].[User],
        [dbo].[Pointage].[Type], [dbo].[Pointage].[PointageDateTime] 
    FROM
        [dbo].[Pointage], [dbo].[Collaborateur]
    WHERE
        [dbo].[Pointage].[User] = [dbo].[Collaborateur].[User] 
        AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [dbo].[Pointage].PointageDateTime, 103) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @LaDate, 103)
        AND CAST(
           CASE WHEN @LEquipe = null and @LeCollaborateur != null 
                   THEN @LeCollaborateur = [dbo].[Collaborateur].[User] 
           CASE WHEN @LEquipe != null THEN @LEquipe = [dbo].[Collaborateur].id_equipe_fk) 
    GO
```

I get syntax errors in the `Cast case` expression. How can I fix this script?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: 1. To test for nulls use `is null/is not null`, not `= or !=`. 2. `Case` is an expression, not control of flow statement. You cannot filter this way because Sql Server does not use boolean datatype. I __think__ you ment `(@LeCollaborateur is null OR [dbo].[Collaborateur].[User] = @LeCollaborateur) AND (@LEquipe is null OR [dbo].[Collaborateur].id_equipe_fk = @LEquipe)` which is fine for smallish tables. 3. CAST requires type: cast (1.22 as nvarchar(10))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
case  when @LEquipe is null and @LeCollaborateur is not null then @LeCollaborateur = [Collaborateur].[User] 
          case when  @LEquipe is not null  then @LEquipe =[Collaborateur].id_equipe_fk end
```

Comment: same error !! I get a syntax error in the first line in this equality `@LeCollaborateur = [Collaborateur].[User]`

Answer (score 3):

it should be like:

```
case  when @LEquipe is null and @LeCollaborateur is not null then @LeCollaborateur = [Collaborateur].[User] 
      when  @LEquipe is not null  then @LEquipe =[Collaborateur].id_equipe_fk end
```

Use this Code:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Passed_Time_Day
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @LaDate date ,
    @LeCollaborateur int null,
    @LEquipe int null 
AS
    select [dbo].[Pointage].[Id],[dbo].[Pointage].[User],[dbo].[Pointage].[Type],[dbo].[Pointage].[PointageDateTime] 
          from  [dbo].[Pointage], [dbo].[Collaborateur]
          where [dbo].[Pointage].[User] = [dbo].[Collaborateur].[User] 
          and  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [dbo].[Pointage].PointageDateTime, 103) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @LaDate, 103)
          and case  when @LEquipe = null and @LeCollaborateur != null then @LeCollaborateur = [dbo].[Collaborateur].[User] 
                    when  @LEquipe != null   then @LEquipe = [dbo].[Collaborateur].id_equipe_fk end

    GO
```